# using variable value in href XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I knw its pretty basic question but I have just started reading it...

I have a variable name

```
<variable name="NAME">
http://www.yahoo.com/<xsl:value-of select="$someothervariable"/>
</variable>
```

and i want to use it in like this

I have used these two approaches but it didn't work

```
<a href="{NAME}">HELLO</a>
<a href="<xsl:value-of select="$NAME"/>
```

Any idea how to achieve this...

Thanks,

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to combine your two approaches:

```
<xsl:variable name="NAME">yourValue</xsl:variable>
<a href="{$NAME}" />
```

Comment: Can you provide some more context on your XSL? It could be a variable scoping issue. Or are there conditionals where your variable is first set?

Comment: Its working fine but there is empty spaces before and after the value in a tag.

Comment: That'll be the newlines you have surrounding your expression in the <variable></variable> tag. Try removing those newlines to get rid of leading/trailing spaces.

Comment: How do you use the same variable URL for multiple anchor tags? If I do another `<a href="{$NAME}" />` tag, on the web page it simply tries to link to "NAME".

Answer (score 1):

```
<a>
    <xsl:attribute name="href">
        <xsl:value-of select="//YOUR_VAR_NAME"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    LINK_TEXT
</a>
```